# External sidebars in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to display several sidebars with custom context.

I suppose that I need to add several additional blogs to be displayed as sidebars. That is for every sidebar I am going to create a little specialized blog.

The question: How to make sidebars *from a different blog* to be displayed in a blog sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to add more than one sidebar, you need to create sidebar for each blog and name it. E.g., want to create sidebar for aboutus.php (created as template page). Create sidebar as sidebar_aboutus.php and add what you want in sidebar to it.
2. Then include that sidebar_aboutus.php in your aboutus.php like this:

   ```
   <?php
     /**
     * Template Name: About us
     *
     * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
     */
   ?>
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <?php include ('sidebar_aboutus.php'); ?>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```
3. Likewise, you can create and include as many sidebars as you need for your different blog pages.